# WPF - Bind Teeview to List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, treeview

I have the following task: 
create Tree which user can modify through app UI - add new Items, delete existing one. TreeView control should be binded to appropriate List in code behind.

Items in tree are CriteriaItem objects.

```
public class Subcriteria
{
    public Subcriteria(string header)
    {
        Title = header;
        subcriterias = new ObservableCollection<Subcriteria>();
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Subcriteria> subcriterias { get; set; }
}

public class Criteria
{
    public Criteria(string header)
    {
        Title = header;
        criterias = new ObservableCollection<Subcriteria>();
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Subcriteria> criterias { get; set; }
}


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    public ObservableCollection<Alternative> _alt = new ObservableCollection<Alternative>();
    Criteria root = new Criteria("root");            
    criteriaBundle.Add(root);
    trvMenu.DataContext = _alt;
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <TreeView Name="trvMenu" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding criteriaBundle}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding criterias}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding subcriterias}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
             </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>          
</TreeView>
```

But it doesn't work. Could you please assist me with binding?

Comment: At first, which is DataContext for TreeView?

Comment: @Spawn Title of CriteriaItem

Comment: Is root a public property in your datacontext?

Comment: Can you post more code? And what exactly doesn`t work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code-behind like this:

1) You should set DataContext, if you use binding

2) You can use only Properties in binding, not fields

My personal advice that You should read about binding basic and MVVM

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        criteriaBundle = new ObservableCollection<CriteriaItem> {new CriteriaItem("root")};
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CriteriaItem> criteriaBundle { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: thanx for advice. I read several resources concerned this topic but   they don't mention anything about DataContext

Comment: @Irina Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Irina I tested code and it works. I attached image. Be sure that you did all right